# List of AWS service specific domains (a.k.a) endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

Trying to find if there is a single document/page that AWS keeps up to date with all the patterns of the domains that the services would use ex:

- <<>>.<<>>.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
- <<>>.<<>>.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com
- <<>>.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had this question earlier in the day. The terminology used by AWS seems to be endpoints.

Here's the current [list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)